# Putting a letter the nth power

Tags: java, math

Trying to print out `a^n` but i get the error `that a and n aren't defined as variables`. Here is what I have now.

```
public class FermatsTheorem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fermatsTheorem(a, n);
    }
    public static void fermatsTheorem(double a, double n){
        double aToTheNthPower = Math.pow(a,n);
        System.out.println("Fermat's Last Theorem: " + aToTheNthPower);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring them and giving them values?

Comment: I plan to do that later, but for right now i want to set up a basic equation using the letters, so I want to print "a^n", except actually be up to the nth power.

Comment: `a` and `n` are just names for some values. If you don't give them any values then you might as well be trying to do `John^Peter`, it doesn't make sense

Comment: You can't 'plan to do that later'. You can't even compile this code until you declare the variables. The compiler has already told you that. Your question and comment make no sense.

Comment: I want to show the initial equation using a as a variable to show how it will be used when a value for it is later input and applied to the equation

Comment: You aren't making any sense here. A program that doesn't compile demonstrates nothing. The compiler has already told you what to do, and so has everyone else. There's no point in posting here if you're going to just ignore what you're told.

Comment: I understand everything being told, and I realize that what I am wanting won't work thanks to rich remer, however most of the responses have not been answering the question I was originally asking, which I admit wasn't completely clear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare values for `a` and `n`.

Imagine you had an equation `x + y = result`. How could you know what the value of `result` is if you don't know the values of `x` and `y`?

Same thing for your case. You are trying to compute what `a^n` equals but you don't give the program any values to compute.

```
public class FermatsTheorem {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = 3.5;
        double n = 2.0;
        fermatsTheorem(a, n);
    }
    public static void fermatsTheorem(double a, double n){
        double aToTheNthPower = Math.pow(a,n);
        System.out.println("Fermat's Last Theorem: " + aToTheNthPower);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a [Symbolic Manipulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system).  This is not a feature of most programming languages.  You can't actually deal with abstracts, only concrete values.  There are quite possibly libraries available to do what you want in your language of choice, but you may also want to look at something like Mathlab.